# Unity Tweak tool fails to start with the error "com.canonical.unity.webapps schema is missing"

Tags: 14.04, unity-tweak-tool

[image]

> com.canonical.unity.webapps
>   In order to work properly, Unity Tweak Tool recommends you install the necessary packages

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the problem. Please check it out.

Comment: -1 to whoever wrote that error message. Yuck. (if they only added a *filename* one could try `apt-file search`).

Comment: @Rmano they did, I found it just fine using apt-file search. the full filename is `com.canonical.unity.webapps.gschema.xml`; maybe you need to run `sudo apt-file update`?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Install the package `unity-webapps-service`

Comment: I have the same problem but can't install the package. I get this error message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 unity-webapps-service : Depends: webapp-container

Comment: sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service IS proper command

Comment: I dont want webapps in my Desktop PC... Why can I not use a tweak tool without having a completely useless Ubuntu browser

Comment: @Mrokii Here, this worked for me. I had the same problem. http://askubuntu.com/a/668336/289337

Comment: @Florian: Wow! For me that pulled 120MB of qt dependencies.

Comment: Does this mean that the package for Unity Tweak Tool should have this package as a dependency but doesn't?

Comment: For me this popped up after 15.04 to 15.10 upgrade.

Comment: No need for webApps-service. Follow this: 
sudo apt install unity-lens-applications    WORKED for me

Answer (score 18):

Just a command line way to do jackyzy823's answer:

```
mkdir tweak;cd tweak
sudo apt-get download unity-webapps-service
ar xvf *
tar xvf data*
sudo mv usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity.webapps.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
cd ..; sudo rm -Rf tweak
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm if you can't get the webapps-service to install. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted both answers. Just a suggestion, though: you might want to specify which answer you mean by 'above' - in this case jackyzy823's answer.

Comment: In my case I didn't install anything. My theme and custom icon pack randomly stopped working and returned to default. Trying to re-configure it with Unity Tweak Tool failed with the same error as the OP.  This answer fixed it.

Comment: In my case, I was getting this error because I actually do not have the `notify-osd` package installed; I am using `xfce4-notifyd` instead. So my fix was exactly as @mchid explained, only I downloaded `notify-osd` instead of `unity-webapps-service`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 14):

A tricky way for this,because i do not want to download so many dependencies for `unity-webapps-service`.

extract the file `com.canonical.unity.webapps.gschema.xml` (you can see it in http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/unity-webapps-service/filelist) in package [`unity-webapps-service`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity-webapps-service),put this file to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` and finally `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` and it works.

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer, as unity-webapps-service refuses to be installed.

Comment: Where do I find the schema file?

Comment: @thesdog go here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity-webapps-service. Download the deb package, and unpack using the instructions in the post below by mchid.

Answer (score 10):

Simple solution.

Just Install necessary packages.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common
```

Comment: Installing this package solves the problem. At least for 14.10.

Comment: I get this error: 

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-webapps-common : Depends: unity-webapps-service (>= 2.3.8-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Synaptic says I have no broken packages.

Comment: how did you know to install `unity-webapps-common` ? It's not mentioned at all in the error screen shown in OP. Is it mystic knowledge that comes to you when you sleep?

Answer (score 4):

I had no problem installing webapps service and webapps common. My exact problem was the package

```
 com.canonical.unity.FileLens
```

was missing. I misread the screenshot in this question, and spent more than half an hour trying to figure out why even though unity webapps service and webapps common are installed unity tweak tool is not working. Finally I found out the above package was missing instead of the one mentioned in the screenshot.

To solve this error, install the `unity-lens-files` package

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-files
```

That's it. Unity Tweak Tool is now working! (finally!)

Answer (score 2):

For those who still need a solution: the problem occurs if one uninstalls the overlay scrollbars. To solve the problem, install the overlay scroll bars again (`sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar`) and disable them via the Unity Tweak Tool itself. (**System > Scrolling**)

Answer (score 2):

In case of **Ubuntu 19 or later**, install the `unity-lens-applications` package by running:

```
sudo apt install unity-lens-applications
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, and effective
type

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-service
```

into the terminal

Comment: yes..dear, that answer in already given above. Installing unity-webapps-service is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need is to use synaptic. Try these:

1. Install synaptic: "sudo apt-get install synaptic" in the terminal.
2. Open Synaptic from the dash or from terminal sudo synaptic.
3. Click on Custom Filters then Missing Recommended Packages.
4. Highlight all and right click mark for installation
5. Click apply on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal and run the following commands. This works for me. Hope it works for you.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd
sudo apt-get install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar
```