# Turned off webapps, now can't relaunch because it requires webapps

Tags: webapps, unity-tweak-tool

I accidentally turned of webapp support in the latest version of the Unity Tweak Tool application. Now I get this error when I try to launch it:

[image: com.canonical.unity.webapps]

How can I turn webapps back on?

Comment: How did you turn it off?

Comment: are you sure you turned it off? and did not -delete- a package? (1st line in the image: "the following schemata is missing")

Comment: Well I can't take a screenshot anymore but there was a toggle somewhere to turn webapps off, and I clicked on that, thinking it was something else (I realised afterwards it was that), but now the program won't start anymore. I haven't removed anything after the time that it worked.

Comment: see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449943/error-launching-unity-tweak-tool-in-ubuntu-14-04 answer: "Install the package unity-webapps-service"